# How to delete a function?

Tags: functions

For what I do I tend to define a lot of functions that I use temporarily. Life span is usually about 1-2 weeks - and then I define a new set of functions.

I was not able to find where these definitions actually are, nor how to delete them just by supplying a function name (which would be useful).

Comment: Why bother? They'll go away if and when you next restart Emacs (unless you're saving them in your `.emacs`).

Comment: @Barmar. See, I didn't know that. My question got edited multiple times. What I do is to define a keyboard macro, save it as a functions, and bind it to a shortcut. Once I am done with what I do, usually define so more and rebind. But the function is still there if I press M-x. Hence the question. PS. I don't know a lot of Emacs internals so it might seem like an obvious question for some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to removing the function definition with [`fmakunbound`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html) and variable binding with [`makunbound`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html), you can also remove the *name* itself with [`unintern`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html).

Note also that, unless you save your definitions in a file (e.g., [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)) and load it, your functions and variables will be gone when you restart Emacs.

Answer (score 13):

Functions are unbound with:

```
(fmakunbound 'NAME)
```

(The equivalent for variables is `makunbound`.)